# Gradient descent Matlab to Python

Tags: python, matlab

I'm halfway through my logistic regression model program and I'm stuck on gradient descent function. I'm translating from Matlab to Python. This is the code for it I got in Matlab (working):

```
function [w func_values] = gradient_descent( obj_fun, w0, epochs, eta )
% Function optimizes obj_fun using gradient descent method. 
% Returns variable w, which minimizes objective function, and values of the
% objective function in all optimization steps (func_values)

% obj_fun - pointer to objective function, that is callable by: obj_fun(w)
% w0 - starting point (initial parameter values)
% epochs - number of epochs / number of algorithm iterations
% eta - learning rate

func_values = [];
w = zeros(size(w0));
w = w0;
for i=1:epochs
    [~, grad] = obj_fun(w);
    w = w-(eta*grad);
    [L, ~] = obj_fun(w);
    func_values(i, 1) = L;
end
end
```

And this is my translation to Python:

```
def gradient_descent(obj_fun, w0, epochs, eta):
    '''
    :param obj_fun: objective function that is going to be minimized (call val,grad = obj_fun(w)).
    :param w0: starting point Mx1
    :param epochs: number of epochs / iterations of an algorithm
    :param eta: learning rate
    :return: function optimizes obj_fun using gradient descent. It returns (w,func_values),
    where w is optimal value of w and func_valus is vector of values of objective function [epochs x 1] calculated for each epoch
    '''
    w = w0
    func_values = []
    for i in range (epochs):
        [val, grad] = obj_fun(w)
        w = w -(eta*grad)
        [val,grad] = obj_fun(w)
        val = func_values[i]
    return (w, func_values)
```

Apparently, I got the value of w correct, the `func_values` aren't fine though. I think the problem is in the `[~, grad]` etc. translation. I've been looking for it but haven't found anything on it yet; how could I properly translate `~` from Matlab to Python? I assume it's skipping rows and assigning columns only to `grad`, and then, in `[L, ~]` it's assigning rows to `L` and skipping columns. If I'm wrong, let me know! The error I get is:

```
    val = func_values[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why is it out of range? There was no range assigned to `func_values` yet. I've tried `[i, 0]` as well, producing this error:

```
    val = func_values[i, 1]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't remember Matlab to help with the translation overall, but you have a problem in Python itself. `func_values` is an empty list that you are trying to index (`val = func_values[i]` is the syntax for "get the value at the i'th index and assign it to `val`", not setting a value); that will fail. You possibly want something like `func_values.append([val, grad])` but I can't understand why you are using the `i` index at all in your loop.

Comment: Well, in the Matlab solution I used `i` to fill the func_values with val a 100 times (100 was the number of epochs). After using your solution, I get an error `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`. I think it might have something to do with the fact that I'm just filling it once. Honestly, the entire func_values is confusing to me. Thank you so much for help though!

Comment: Then this really is a case of "lost in translation" because nothing in your code adds anything to `func_values` at all; if somehow it didn't error, it would be unchanged at the end (still empty). You almost certainly want `append` somewhere to actually add values to the list, and possibly use the `i` index to retrieve those values from `obj_fun` for specific epochs. Actually, you seem to be using python almost in complete reverse. Can you give a short sample of what `print(obj_fun(w))` gives? That reduces the dependency of people knowing both languages to answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, because I'm only implementing functions and I can't access the main or test files, which I got provided for the assignment, and the only print I get is the one already written in main (so when I write `print`, I don't see the output anyway). I did manage to get that `func_values` should result in an array with just one `int` per row, so I suppose it's only gonna be `val`. Sorry if this isn't helping... I'm really trying to get this one figured out. I think `func_values.append([val])` should make it work, but it doesn't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One of the main differences between MATLAB and Python is that in MATLAB, arrays will automatically resize themselves to fit your data. I.e.,

```
func_values = []
func_values(10, 1) = 3
```

will create a 10x1 matrix for you and put 3 in that position. While this is super convenient, its actually pretty bad practice: array resizing takes a lot of computational overhead. MATLAB will sometimes warn you about it when it sees it happening, with the message "consider pre-allocating for speed".

In python, you're forced to do the preallocation. With that in mind, your function should look more like the following:

```
def gradient_descent(obj_fun, w0, epochs, eta):

    # Initialize variables
    w = w0
    func_values = np.zeros(epochs)  # This will create an empty list of len _epochs_

    # Run optimization
    for i in range(epochs):
        val, grad = obj_fun(w)
        if i != 0:  # This will give you the same func_values as the MATLAB
            func_values[i-1] = val  # assignments happen left-to-right.
        w = w - (eta * grad)

    # You'll have to do one last evaluation if you want the value at the last w
    val, grad = obj_fun(w)
    func_values[-1] = val

    return w, func_values
```

An aside, your function in MATLAB seems pretty inefficient: you calculate `val, grad` twice for every value of `w`, just to get the extra `func_value` at the end. This version will return a slightly offset version of func_values with only one evaluation per w, with a bit more code you could get the same answer out.

*Edit*: func_values should now match the MATLAB version...

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful! I'll go through this and go back to you in a bit.

Comment: the pre-allocation is actually numpy-specific, you could certainly do `func_values = []`, `func_values += [val]` in the loop. But you're probably better off substituting `func_values = [[]] * epochs` with `func_values = np.zeros(epochs)` if you can use the numpy library

Comment: Ok so I went through it and it seems logical to me - thanks, this is much simpler and straightforward! I still get an error though. I used numpy, went through debugging and, weirdly enough, I get the right values for `func_values` but only starting at the third place - aka first `func_value` is third `func_value` in my code. First `func_value` in mine is `nan`, and second is some other value which doesn't fit. I tried a couple varations with `i` and it didn't change anything (like using i-1 etc.).

Comment: So in your previous code, for each loop, you calculate (1) calculate val, (2) update w, and (3) calculate (and store) val. So the val calculations of (3) and (1) are equivalent for the majority of the loop iterations. In my version, I just store the initial `val` at the start of the loop. I'll edit the answer to make it a bit more straightforward.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much!!! :) The only thing I changed was `np.zeros((epochs,1))` since I wanted it printed out as a single row and before, I got like seven columns with it (I guess that's how epochs were formed). Thank you, I get it now and also it's working, awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

You have not adequately understood non matlab languages enough to know what you are doing.  You need to learn more about python before you attempt this problem, you make many mistakes that wouldn't be made if you understood the language well enough.  To help I'll go through my parsing of your code and what is wrong with your python.   Given that you know matlab, you should be able to merely go through [this official python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) to understand all the constructs of the python language to a degree in which you could do this conversion properly.  Going through this tutorial should only take a weekend, if that, and will teach you all the basics of the language.  Its made for people who already know a language already.

```
function [w func_values] = gradient_descent( obj_fun, w0, epochs, eta )
% Function optimizes obj_fun using gradient descent method. 
% Returns variable w, which minimizes objective function, and values of the
% objective function in all optimization steps (func_values)

% obj_fun - pointer to objective function, that is callable by: obj_fun(w)
% w0 - starting point (initial parameter values)
% epochs - number of epochs / number of algorithm iterations
% eta - learning rate

func_values = [];
w = zeros(size(w0));
w = w0;
for i=1:epochs
    [~, grad] = obj_fun(w);
    w = w-(eta*grad);
    [L, ~] = obj_fun(w);
    func_values(i, 1) = L;
end
end
```

To go over what has happened here, you have made a matlab function, called `gradient_descent` which takes in four parameters and returns two values, w and func_values.

```
%creating an empty matrix
func_values = [];
% creating a matrix of zeros whos size is taken from w0's size, which we 
% don't know and could make this two dimensional or one dimensional or three 
% dimensional, there is max size for dimensionalilty in matlab. 
w = zeros(size(w0));
% matlab assignment is copy by value unless you inherit from handle, so you 
% are copying by value of the w0, and you don't even need the previous line, 
% but I digress.  
w = w0;
% you appear to be using the wrong nomenclature for w0, which is usually the 
% input node vector to a nueral network, youve used it as the 
% initial state of the wieghts in the graph.  

%for i = 1, 2, 3,... i = epochs
for i=1:epochs
    % get the gradient difference between expected output objective 
    % function, and the output of w. Assume objective returns gradients at 
    % each point in the graph, with sizeof(grad) == sizeof(w)
    [~, grad] = obj_fun(w);
    % multiply the gradient and learning rate and subtract both matricies 
    w = w-(eta*grad);
    % getting the real value of objective function when applied to graph?
    [L, ~] = obj_fun(w);
    % adding to list this objective function value. 
    func_values(i, 1) = L;
end
end
```

Now onto the python, you've defined a function gradient descent that takes four parameters, and returns w and func_values.

```
def gradient_descent(obj_fun, w0, epochs, eta):
    '''
    :param obj_fun: objective function that is going to be minimized (call val,grad = obj_fun(w)).
    :param w0: starting point Mx1
    :param epochs: number of epochs / iterations of an algorithm
    :param eta: learning rate
    :return: function optimizes obj_fun using gradient descent. It returns (w,func_values),
    where w is optimal value of w and func_valus is vector of values of objective function [epochs x 1] calculated for each epoch
    '''
    # assigned by object reference from the get go... so you will be 
    # modifying w0 if you modify w. Bad, you need a deepcopy
    w = w0
    # intializing empty list of func values
    func_values = []
    # for i = 0, 1, 2, 3... i = epochs-1.  Notice how i starts at 0 and ends 
    # at max-1?
    for i in range (epochs):
        # this isn't matlab, you can just do val,grad instead here. 
        # otherwise does what it did in matlab. 

        [val, grad] = obj_fun(w)
        # you can't subtract two lists, and multiplying lists results in the 
        # number of elements being repeated n times, not multiplying each 
        # element by n. This should give you an error. 
        w = w -(eta*grad)
        # you can also use _ to represent ~ in matlab
        [val,grad] = obj_fun(w)
        # what... doing backward order assignment? func_values doesn't even 
        # have anything in it either, it is just = [].
        # you can't do func_values[i] = val either, since the memory at 
        # position i doesn't exist.  You need to do func_values.append(val) 
        # this should give you an error.   
        val = func_values[i] 
    # python automatically converts this into a tuple, no need for the 
    # parenthesis. explicit return in python. 
    return (w, func_values)
```

You need to go over python's rules badly.  You can't just copy and paste matlab and expect it to work.  Fixing the issues I raised above will fix your program assuming your objective function, w0, ecpochs and eta are all proper. You'll need to implement the array based subtraction and element wise multiplication yourself unless you use Numpy.

You'll need to do something like this:

```
def gradient_descent(obj_fun, w0, epochs, eta):
    # shallow copy of w0, works for primitives like numbers, won't work for 
    # other things like multidimensional arrays since that is a list of 
    # lists
    w = w0[:]
    # to deep copy, you need to import copy first, then do 
    #    w = copy.deecopy(w0)
    func_values = []
    for i in range (epochs):
        val, grad = obj_fun(w)
        # list comprehension generates a list, here I'm multiplying eta for 
        # each element in grad, _, and that becomes a list.
        descent_list = [eta*_ for _ in grad]
        # you'll need to create your own subtraction function to subtract 
        # each element, you'll need to iterate through each list and 
        # subtract the values from eachother and return a list of those 
        # values
        w = subtract(w, descent_list)
        val,grad = obj_fun(w)
        func_values.append(val)
    return w, func_values
```

Comment: All I've taken from reading this is a list of things the OP did wrong and little in the way of getting them to a functioning program. Some parts might be constructive in helping transition, but if you're going to go to this effort then a proper translation would probably be more useful.

Comment: @roganjosh If they fixed these things they would have a properly functioning program, do you want me to do their job for them?

Comment: You're under no obligation to do anything. I'm remarking that, if you took the time to write a full critique of the approach, a slightly softer delivery may help. The OP did focus the question on just the index error.

Comment: @roganjosh Op also apparently fixed that, stating " I think func_values.append([val]) should make it work, but it doesn't".  So it seems to me like they just want us to solve the entire problem for them instead of actually understanding what they are doing, the errors I get from his code are quite obvious.

Comment: Upvote for your edit. Having seen a lot of "give me the code/ do the translation for me" posts, I think this question was genuinely quite specific and used the matlab code to put things into context, not that they wanted the whole translation (even though there was a lot of misunderstanding in general). With the addition of the last edit, I think this answer is much more useful now.

Comment: @snb This forum is literally for helping out with code. The question I asked is clear and I don't appreciate you saying that I'm a slacker who just wants you to write it for me... If you don't like my question, ignore it. Your added code after editing isn't working for me, either. I get the same error as before. `w` parameter was already fine, so I think there's no need to change the code for it, unless it's about improving the style. As for the append method, it was already suggested by roganjosh and as I said, it didn't solve the problem either.

Comment: @LinK,  did you implement a subtract function? you couldn't just copy and pasted my code and expect it to work, In the comments I tell you that you need to implement some things yourself.   Also, the append code you had doesn't work, period, because you are trying to append a list to another list instead of a value to the list, this is fixed in mine.  These are basic things that you should understand about python before starting this endeavor.  And also I've gotten this to run on my end, if you can't you simply haven't tried hard enough, the subtract code is literally two lines.